# XSL: is there a fast alternative to using a variable-in-a-predicate?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Edited in a feeble attempt to clarify. The system converts XML into another XML via the XSL processor.

I'm doing some XSL rule stuff for a machine that has plug-in cards. The cards will supply their own XSL rules to the main host, which in turn will colate these into one super-XSL file to be processed by itself, and also sent over to web browsers who've HTTP'd onto the machine. The browser is used to set configuration items for the machine, and the XSL is there to change and/or hide and/or unhide some of the XML. To simplify my query here, I've invented a small example.

When a user configures an item to be of type B, (a choice of several such as A, B, C, ...), then the next two items are to be changed (in some way) too. In the real deal, there's an attribute "hidden" set to true or false, and also child elements which are set. The next two items in the real thing are to be hidden, and also child elements changed.

When the user changes the item from a type B to say a type A, then I need to work out which other nodes need to have their 'hidden' attribute set to false. The user will change the child elements as they see fit.

All of this is "circular", and ordered, so if a node is set to type B, and it's the last node (no following-sibling's) then the affected nodes are the first in the set. (In XPath terms, if node[4] is type B, then nodes [1] and [2] are to be hidden and changed).

So, for my example here, I have as an input XML:

```
<topline>
  <midline type="A" name="mid1" hidden="false"><source name="off"/></midline>
  <midline type="B" name="mid2" hidden="false"><source name="input 1"/></midline>
  <midline type="A" name="mid3" hidden="false"><source name="off"/></midline>
  <midline type="A" name="mid4" hidden="false"><source name="off"/></midline>
</topline>
```

and the XSL will change this to:

```
<topline>
  <midline type="A" name="mid1" hidden="false"><source name="off"/></midline>
  <midline type="B" name="mid2" hidden="false"><source name="input 1"/></midline>
  <midline type="A" name="mid3" hidden="true"><source name="input 1"/></midline>
  <midline type="A" name="mid4" hidden="true"><source name="input 1"/></midline>
</topline>
```

Now if the user changes his mind, and changes mid2 to be a type A:

```
<topline>
  <midline type="A" name="mid1" hidden="false"><source name="off"/></midline>
  <midline type="A" name="mid2" hidden="false"><source name="input 1"/></midline>
  <midline type="A" name="mid3" hidden="true"><source name="input 1"/></midline>
  <midline type="A" name="mid4" hidden="true"><source name="input 1"/></midline>
</topline>
```

then the XSL will unhide the circular following siblings of mid2, so result should be:

```
<topline>
  <midline type="A" name="mid1" hidden="false"><source name="off"/></midline>
  <midline type="A" name="mid2" hidden="false"><source name="input 1"/></midline>
  <midline type="A" name="mid3" hidden="false"><source name="input 1"/></midline>
  <midline type="A" name="mid4" hidden="false"><source name="input 1"/></midline>
</topline>
```

It is this second step I am struggling with. What I've done to solve it is, to me, rather ugly but perhaps unavoidable given what I'm trying to achieve isn't really XSL friendly.

What I've landed up doing :

```
<xsl:for-each select="topline">
  <xsl:for-each select="midline">
    <xsl:variable name="masterPosition" select="position()"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="@type='B'>
        hide the next two nodes. This is easy: 
            translate($masterPosition, '1234', '2341')
        works nicely.
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:variable name="prior1" select="translate(masterPosition, '1234', '4123')"/>
          <xsl:variable name="test1" select="../midline[$prior1]/source[1]/@name='off'"/>
          this second line doesn't work: I only get the first node, always. 
          So instead I have 
          <xsl:variable name="test2">
              <xsl:choice>
                  <xsl:when test="$masterPosition='1'"><xsl:value-of select="../midline[4]/source"/></xsl:when>
                  and so on for the other masterPositions
              </xsl:choice>
          </xsl:variable>
          and this is repeated for a few other variables, one each for each relevant
          prior position and for the fields I need to change. I then use these
          variables to change the XML - there's something in the main machine's
          processing to enable this, I believe it is non-standard, so please ignore: 
          (At least it doesn't run against Xalan).
          <set key={$test2}/@hidden, value="false")/>             
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  <xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Is there a more elegant way of doing this that you can think of? If not, don't worry, I believe my hack will work, and also shouldn't consume too many MIPS.

I can't use `<xsl:key>` as our system doesn't cope: we have multiple XSL sources which get colated into one, and the colation script (out of my control) simply doesn't understand `<xsl:key>`, so if there is a solution using keys, I can't use it.

Thanks
Richard

Comment: You need to make sure that you properly mark all tags as being code in the markdown editor. It seems that in the "What I want to do" there are some tags missing, at least I don't get what you want to achieve.

Comment: That's odd. The formatting isn't great, but (to me, but then I wrote it) seems clear enough: compare the first XML to the second: the source names change for "mid1" and "mid4" because they precede, in a circular manner, "mid2". I need a way to, having come across say the node for "mid4", determine if it is related to "mid2" because when processing "mid2", it changed "mid4". If this is the case, I leave it alone, otherwise I have other things I need to do with it ('it' being mid4 as my example). I hope this helps, it sounds a bit rambling to me :-)

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete solution for the reversal from type-B to type-A. :)

Comment: I don't think this question is complete defined: If there is no indication of the last "change", then it should be defined wich "static" change has more precedence, B type (I would assume this) or A type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do what you want, without keys, based on template matching:

```
<!-- start with the identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- <midline>s that have two preceding siblings -->
<xsl:template match="midline[@type='A'][count(preceding-sibling::midline) &gt; 1]">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="source">
    <xsl:with-param name="circular" select="
      preceding-sibling::midline[position() &lt;= 2]
    " />
  </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<!-- <midline>s that have one preceding sibling -->
<xsl:template match="midline[@type='A'][count(preceding-sibling::midline) = 1]">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="source">
    <xsl:with-param name="circular" select="
      (preceding-sibling::midline|../midline[last()])
    " />
  </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<!-- <midline>s that have no preceding sibling -->
<xsl:template match="midline[@type='A'][count(preceding-sibling::midline) = 0]">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="source">
    <xsl:with-param name="circular" select="
      ../midline[position() &gt; last() - 2]
    " />
  </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<!-- this template creates a new node with the wanted source -->
<xsl:template match="midline" mode="source">
  <xsl:param name="circular" select="." />
  <xsl:variable name="prevB" select="$circular[@type = 'B' and not(@mode = off)]" />
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
    <xsl:attribute name="hidden">
      <xsl:value-of select="boolean($prevB)" />
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$prevB">
        <xsl:copy-of select="$prevB/source" />
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:copy-of select="source" />
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

For your sample input, the output would be:

```
<topline>
  <midline type="A" name="mid1" hidden="false"><source name="off"/></midline>
  <midline type="B" name="mid2" hidden="false"><source name="input 1"/></midline>
  <midline type="A" name="mid3" hidden="true"><source name="input 1"/></midline>
  <midline type="A" name="mid4" hidden="true"><source name="input 1"/></midline>
</topline>
```

*Note that your description contradicts your sample output - this is what you would get when strictly following your description, unless I misunderstood you.*

The `<xsl:with-param>` is used to pass in the two nodes that are the "circular preceding-siblings" (or the empty node-set in case of `@type=B'` nodes).

The template `<xsl:template match="midline" mode="source">` uses that parameter: if it is there, it checks your condition (i.e. one of them is `@type='B'` and it is not `@mode='off'`).

If such a node exists, it copies its `<source>`, else it copies the original `<source>`.

Comment: Hi Tomalak. Thank you very much, I'll see if I can apply this, I have yet to properly understand template matching. I also don't think I've phrased my question very well: I need to work out the reverse: is say 'mid4' set to 'input 1' because of 'mid2' being type B, or because the input XML had that value already. If the former, I leave it alone, otherwise I can change it. (Of course 'input 1' can be one of many values). I'll digest your answer to see if it has the solution I need. Thanks for taking the time, Richard.

Comment: @Richard: I've change my code in the meantime. I'm afraid I still do not understand 100% when which changes should apply. Please edit your question and create an unambiguous description of which values you want to change or keep based on which criteria. *(maybe when you understood my code it's easier for you to point out where I'm mis-interpreting your description)*

Comment: Hi Tomalak. Thanks again: I've edited my query, but I understand your solution and will rework my stuff accordingly. I haven't make good use of Xpath stuff, which you have done. Back to the think tank. Regards Richard

Comment: @Tomalak: The OP wants the `hidden` attributes to be reversed and I don't see your transformation referencing `hidden` attributes at all ? See my answer for what I think the OP is asking for.

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev: The OP changed his question after I gave my answer. The `hidden` attribute did not exist until then, and I did not yet have time to refactor my answer.

Comment: @Richard: I've changed my answer once more to include the `hidden` attribute into the process (I take it that the two "circularly following" `type="A"` nodes should be `hidden="true"`).

Answer (score 1):

**To do the reverse transformation, you want this**:

**when this transformation is applied on the following (provided) XML where the user has just changed `type='B'` into `type='A'`**:

```
<topline>
    <midline type="A" name="mid1" hidden="false">
        <source name="off"/>
    </midline>
    <midline type="A" name="mid2" hidden="false">
        <source name="input 1"/>
    </midline>
    <midline type="A" name="mid3" hidden="true">
        <source name="input 1"/>
    </midline>
    <midline type="A" name="mid4" hidden="true">
        <source name="input 1"/>
    </midline>
</topline>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced** (`hidden="false"` is set for the ex-B-type next two circular siblings):

```
<topline>
   <midline type="A" name="mid1" hidden="false">
      <source name="off"/>
   </midline>
   <midline type="A" name="mid2" hidden="false">
      <source name="input 1"/>
   </midline>
   <midline type="A" name="mid3" hidden="false">
      <source name="input 1"/>
   </midline>
   <midline type="A" name="mid4" hidden="false">
      <source name="input 1"/>
   </midline>
</topline>
```

**with this source XML file (real circular siblings):**

```
<topline>
    <midline type="A" name="mid1" hidden="true">
        <source name="off"/>
    </midline>
    <midline type="A" name="mid2" hidden="false">
        <source name="input 1"/>
    </midline>
    <midline type="A" name="mid3" hidden="false">
        <source name="input 1"/>
    </midline>
    <midline type="A" name="mid4" hidden="true">
        <source name="input 1"/>
    </midline>
</topline>
```

**again the wanted, correct result is produced**.

**Do note**: The use of the XPath `mod` operator to determine the circular siblings positions.

Comment: +1. I should have thought of using `mod()`, this is much nicer than my approach.